# How to return a ROWTYPE in PL/SQL and retrieve it in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I have a PL/SQL function , that returns a ROWTYPE. I need to call this function from Java and retrieve the data ( as an array, a map, a struct, a class,whatever, I really don't care , I just need it, preferably without having to screw around the PL/SQL code, like changing the return type of the function). I have looked into multiple "solutions" and forums but I did not find the answer.
I have already tried to register the out parameter as a struct and a class , none worked.
This is my PL/SQL function:

```
  FUNCTION DAR_CLIENTE(cedula VARCHAR2) RETURN CLIENTE%ROWTYPE AS
  RET CLIENTE%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    -- TAREA: Se necesita implantación para FUNCTION P_CLIENTE.DAR_CLIENTE
    SELECT * INTO RET FROM CLIENTE WHERE Persona_cedula=cedula;
    RETURN RET;
  END DAR_CLIENTE;
```

This is my java code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
    Properties info = new Properties();
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_USER_NAME, DB_USER);
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_PASSWORD, DB_PASSWORD);
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_DEFAULT_ROW_PREFETCH, "20");

    OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ods.setURL(DB_URL);
    ods.setConnectionProperties(info);

    // With AutoCloseable, the connection is closed automatically.
    try (OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) ods.getConnection()) {
        // Get the JDBC driver name and version
        DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
        System.out.println("Driver Name: " + dbmd.getDriverName());
        System.out.println("Driver Version: " + dbmd.getDriverVersion());
        // Print some connection properties
        System.out.println("Default Row Prefetch Value is: " + connection.getDefaultRowPrefetch());
        System.out.println("Database Username is: " + connection.getUserName());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(connection.getSchema());
        // Perform a database operation

        Map<String, Class<?>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
        myMap.put("P09551_1_5.CLIENTE", Cliente.class);

        connection.setTypeMap(myMap);
        CallableStatement storedProc = connection
                .prepareCall("{? = call P09551_1_5.p_cliente.dar_cliente('1144102435')}");

        storedProc.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.JAVA_STRUCT);
        storedProc.execute();

    }
}
```

I am using ojdbc8.jar.

This information is printed to the console at the start of the program:

```
Driver Name: Oracle JDBC driver
Driver Version: 18.3.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue by changing the return type to a SYS_REFCURSOR, like this:

```
FUNCTION DAR_CLIENTE(cedula VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
  RET SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    -- TAREA: Se necesita implantación para FUNCTION P_CLIENTE.DAR_CLIENTE
    OPEN RET FOR
    SELECT * FROM CLIENTE WHERE Persona_cedula=cedula;
    RETURN RET;
  END DAR_CLIENTE;
```

Java code as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
    Properties info = new Properties();
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_USER_NAME, DB_USER);
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_PASSWORD, DB_PASSWORD);
    info.put(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_DEFAULT_ROW_PREFETCH, "20");

    OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ods.setURL(DB_URL);
    ods.setConnectionProperties(info);

    // With AutoCloseable, the connection is closed automatically.
    try (OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) ods.getConnection()) {
        // Get the JDBC driver name and version
        DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
        System.out.println("Driver Name: " + dbmd.getDriverName());
        System.out.println("Driver Version: " + dbmd.getDriverVersion());
        // Print some connection properties
        System.out.println("Default Row Prefetch Value is: " + connection.getDefaultRowPrefetch());
        System.out.println("Database Username is: " + connection.getUserName());
        System.out.println("Schema: "+connection.getSchema());
        System.out.println();
        // Perform a database operation

        Map<String, Class<?>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
        myMap.put("P09551_1_5.CLIENTE", Cliente.class);

        connection.setTypeMap(myMap);
        CallableStatement storedProc = connection
                .prepareCall("{? = call P09551_1_5.p_cliente.dar_cliente('1144102435')}");

        storedProc.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        storedProc.execute();
        ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) storedProc.getObject(1);
        ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = meta.getColumnCount();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                System.out.println(meta.getColumnLabel(i)+":"+resultSet.getObject(i).toString());
            }
            //System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));

        }

    }
}
```

Getting this response on the console (I did it so all fields would be printed with their column labels, though this particular table only has one column):

```
Driver Name: Oracle JDBC driver
Driver Version: 18.3.0.0.0
Default Row Prefetch Value is: 20
Database Username is: P09551_1_5
Schema: P09551_1_5

PERSONA_CEDULA:1144102435
```

Here is the source of the solution:
https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-cursor-example/

Answer (score 0):

#### Using a third party: jOOQ

If using a third party library is acceptable to you, you could use [jOOQ's stored procedure support](https://blog.jooq.org/the-best-way-to-call-stored-procedures-from-java-with-jooq/), which includes support for PL/SQL package types. jOOQ's code generator will generate a class `PCliente` containing a method `darCliente()` for you, which you can call as follows:

```java
ClienteRecord result = PCliente.darCliente(
    configuration, // This wraps your JDBC connection
    "1144102435"
);
```

No need to wrap your head around JDBC bindings. Everything is type safe. The `ClienteRecord` is the same data type as if you ran that `SELECT` query directly with jOOQ.

#### The SQL generated by jOOQ

Because ojdbc still (I think?) can't bind all PL/SQL package types, jOOQ flattens your `%ROWTYPE` into individual bind values, e.g. like this (actual SQL will vary, because it's trickier than that, considering all the edge cases)

```sql
DECLARE
  r CLIENTE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  r := P_CLIENTE.DAR_CLIENTE(?);
  ? := r.COL1;
  ? := r.COL2;
  ? := r.COL3;
END;
```

Of course, instead of using jOOQ, you could generate this SQL yourself and continue binding to JDBC directly.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.